# Pager View Controller's root view's got different size than subsequent View Controller's

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, pager

I'm using `DMPagerViewController`, but I tried used other ones, and they all appear to have similar behaviors.

I set up a git to try to understand what's happening: https://github.com/LucasCoelho/DMPager-Example

Basically I added twice, from the storyboard, a ViewController to the `DMPagerViewController` and set it as the `rootViewController` of a `UINavigationController` who is the window's `rootViewController`

The view controller contains a `UIButton` that pushes another instance of the same ViewController and a label who is set at `viewWillAppear(_:)` who displays `view.frame.size.height`

What I'm struggling with is that the height of the first view shown doesn't match with the subsequent views pushed.

Can anyone please tell me why?

Here's some code if you don't want to download it on github:

**App Delegate's** `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
pagerController = DMPagerViewController(viewControllers:[firstViewController, secondViewController])

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pagerController)
navController.navigationBar.translucent = false

window?.rootViewController = navController
```

Comment: So, Do you want to match all view the frame height?

Comment: What I really want is the views to look the same and not to use a translucent UINavigationBar

Comment: Embedded `UINavigationController`. Relationship "root view controller" to View Controller. it works for you I think your problem is solved

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood. Are you suggesting I don't use pagerController?

Comment: click on `ViewController` then `Menu=>Editor=>Embed In=> Navigation Controller` [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uZM6x.png

Comment: @Yuyutsu nothing changes when I do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76619/discussion-between-lucas-and-yuyutsu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this bug because the subviews of DMPagerViewController do not fit to the parent view, because, there are no contraints and no autoresizing mask to update them, that is why the bug appear only in DMPagerViewController and not in `ViewController`.
So to fix that, just uncomment this line in the initializer of DMPagerViewController :

```
//   _scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

Now, the bug is fixed but the content height of scrollView is larger than view height.

**Explanation** :

We get the real frame of the view only when this method is called [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews), and because we calculate the content size of the scrollView before that, so we get a wrong value. To fix that, we should add some code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or in `viewDidAppear` (this two methods called when autolayout is completed.), I prefer `viewDidAppear` because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self adjustControllerLayout];
    [self adjustPagerNavigationBarOnScroll];
}
```

You can find more informations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH13-SW1)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the navigation bar.

`DMPagerViewController` has it's own custom navigation bar so it doesn't seem to consider the navigation bar of the `UINavigationController`.

If you use the Debug View Hierarchy mode in Xcode you'll see that the view it's not shown completely on screen.

If you set `navController.navigationBar.translucent = true`, you'll see the you're label will report the same size all the time.

Comment: navController.navigationBar.translucent = true you mean?

Comment: We're on the right track. But even with that modification, why is the button placed differently on the screen?

Comment: If you scroll the view up, you'll see that you can get it to have the same position as the one pushed.  It seems as the DMPagerViewController doesn't play nice with UINavigationController.